# (p->q) v (q->p) with Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, deduction

Well, indeed I have the answer to this exercise but I don't understand some steps. From 6 to 17 are OK for me but from 2 to 5 and then when step 5 is again called in step 10 is something I don't get very well.

I mean, could you re use a formula from a conditional box from above in other one? I would never have thought that. [image]

Comment: 2-5) assumed "p to q", derived a contradiction and concluded with "not (p to q)".

Comment: 6-13) assumed q and derived "p to q" (this can be dona more simply by to-intro). Now this contradicts "not (p to q)" derived above in step 5) and we can conclude with p, and from it with "q to p" by to-intro.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol `F` stands for 'False' or 'Contradiction'.   Negation is at times defined as "this implies a contradiction".

> `~P` is equivalent to  `P => F`

Your system reuses the Conditional Elimination and Introduction symbols (=>E, =>I), but the inferences are more commonly known as Negation Elimination and Introduction.

Just as we may infer `F` from `P` and `P => F` by Conditional Elimination, so too may we infer `F` from `P` and `~P` by Negation Elimination.

```
|  P
|  P=>F
|  F     Conditional Elimination (=>E)

|  P
|  ~P
|  F     Negation Elimination
```

**Or basically:** We may derive `F` from any two statements which contradict each other.  Such as lines 5 and 10, `~(p->q)` and `p->q`.  Also line 1 `~((p->q)+(q->p)` and 4 (and later 15) `(p->q)+(q->p)`

---

Likewise: Just as we may infer `P => F` when we can derive `F` under assumed `P` by Conditional Introduction, so similarly we may infer `~P` when we can derive `F` under assumption of `P` by Negation Introduction.  These are assumption discharge rules

```
|  |_ P    Assumption
|  |  :
|  |  F
|  P => F  Conditional Introduction (=>I)

|  |_ P    Assumption
|  |  :
|  |  F
|  ~P      Negation Introduction
```

**Note:** what your system calls RAA is more commonly known as Double Negation Elimination (DNE). (RAA is more usually where: we may infer `P` when we can derive `F` under assumption of `~P`).

---

```
   |_
 1.|  |_ ~((p -> q) + (q -> p))    Assumption
 2.|  |  |_ (p -> q)               Assumption
 3.|  |  |  (p -> q) + (q -> p)    2, Disjunction Introduction
 4.|  |  |  F                      1,3 Negation Elimination 
 5.|  |  ~(p -> q)                 2-4 Negation Introduction
 6.|  |  |_ q                      Assumption
 7.|  |  |  |_ ~p                  Assumption
 8.|  |  |  |  |_ p                Assumption
 9.|  |  |  |  |  q                6 Reiteration
10.|  |  |  |  p -> q              8-9 Conditional Introduction
11.|  |  |  |  F.                  5,10 Negation Elimination
12.|  |  |  ~~p                    7-11 Negation Introduction
13.|  |  |  p                      12   Double Negation Elimination
14.|  |  q -> p                    6-13 Conditional Introduction
15.|  |  (p -> q) + (q -> p)       14 Disjunction Introduction
16.|  |  F                         1,15 Negation Elimination
17.|  ~~((p -> q) + (q -> p))      1-16 Negation Introduction
18.|  (p -> q) + (q -> p)          17 Double Negation Elimination
```

---

> I mean, could you re use a formula from a conditional box from above in other one? I would never have thought that.

Yes.  This is the Rule of Reiteration used on line 8.  You can restate something from a lower context.  Think of it as 'moving into the box', if you like.

Usually Reiteration is not needed to be explicitly used; you may just refer to statements from ancestral contexts.

Remember you cannot do the reverse.  You cannot 'move out of the box'.

Answer (score 0):

Assume ~ [ (p-->q) v (q -->p)].

Using DeMorgan, infer : ~ (p-->q) & ~ (q-->p)

Using &-elim, infer

(1) ~ (p-->q)

(2) ~ (q-->p)

Using ~ ( A& ~B) as a definition of material implication, and Double Negation  infer

- from (1) : p & ~Q
- from (2) : q& ~p

Using &-intro, & commutativity and &-associativity, and finally &-elim, rearrange (p & ~q)&( q& ~p) to get the contradiction (p&~p).

Finally, using ~ intro, infer that the original assumption was false.

Double negation will then allow you to infer that the goal-statement was true.

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying but I am not allowed to use DeMorgan or similars. What I mean is that any further than MP, MT, &E, &I, vE, vI, ->, <->, RAA and Hyp rules are forbidden. That's why I still don't get the solution given. For me there's no point of 2-5 and from steps 7 and 8 I could get easlily a contradiction suitable for "p". Literal later used in 13 for "q->p".

Comment: @daenius.-are you allowed to use an equivalence for (X--> Y) ?

Comment: what do you mean? "-X v Y" ? This kind of "quick" transformations or equivalences are not allowed. For example, if we use Modus Ponens (MP as above) is because we have this scenario: p, p->q, so we have q

Comment: @daenius.- This is a rather demanding logical system. How is it called?

Comment: don't worry. I've found the solution. Indeed It was a little different from the image from above. Thanks anyway